# Why do we check for overlapping fragments in OnCreate? (from the documentation)

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html), we have to check if we restore an activity, in order to avoid "overlapping fragments" : why?

Either the activity is destroyed and the fragment is destroyed, so we have to recreate both of them. Or the fragment is retained so that it keeps some data. But in this code, we check if we restore the activity, and if we do, we return the function to avoid "overlapping fragments" :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;//**HERE**
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity stores information about added fragments in its fragment manager. This information persists after configuration changes. Also fragment can save their state, if you want. You can read about retained fragment, which will not be recreated after configuration changes.

**Suggestion:**

You used fragment manager to add your fragment to activity. After activity recreation the fragment is still tied to the recreated activity.

You added your fragment via **add** method, and if `onCreate` method will be called again (for example after rotation), you will add another fragment to your activity.

To avoid it you can use **replace** instead of **add**, but in this case replaced fragment will lose your data (which you saved in savedinstancestate for your fragment, so after rotation fragment's savedInstanceState will be null).

So better to add fragment this way:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment()
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());                
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .add(R.id.fragment_container,firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Understanding activity and fragment lifecycle is very important. I recommend to read related topics on android developers website or from other sources.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zr5QLH4Qy4